# Smartphone hardware requirement for android OCR app?

Tags: android, image-processing, hardware, ocr, requirements

I want to make an OCR app for android smartphones.I am wondering if someone can tell me how much RAM and processor will be enough for image processing involved in it?I am trying to extract all the text from a printed A4 page in one go, how much should be the camera resolution for having a clear image of all characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience the most important hardware requirement might not be RAM and processor but rather camera auto-focus feature. If mobile device does not have auto-focus feature then in majority of cases you can't get proper scanning results.

Second, mobile device cameras (at time of this writing) are not suitable for A4 document scanning in one pass (unless you have a very large font on the document :). The quality of scanning results will be poor even with top quality mobile devices. Good results can be achieved with documents that are about one third the size of A4 documents with mid and high-level devices.

Disclaimer: I work for a company that has developed own mobile OCR and other mobile vision software that are used across different industries.

Comment: Abbyy or is there another one?

Comment: @empedokles there are several mobile OCRs these days. Microblink being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Same as with most questions related to hardware requirements:
You'll probably find out by testing with different hardware setups.
As you'll need to test Android apps with various devices anyway, that should not be a big deal.
We can't know the font size and neither can we estimate the complexity of your algorithms. Also I assume that the font(s) which you use has an important influence, depending on the distinctness of their chars rendering.
Plus, if the image is blurred, that'll negatively influence the resources you need.

Comment: I think may be I should go for the max that I can afford in order to avoid problems.I was hoping probably some android OCR gurus could tell me.Anyways thanks for the response